# How to display specific number of items?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to create a view with charts that can be scrolled left and right (starting from the right). I've already done this using LazyRow and set reverseLayout to true.

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)

LazyRow(
    reverseLayout = true,
    state = scrollState
) {
    items(charts) {data ->
        ChartBar()
    }
}
```

My chart is swappable and displays correctly.

My problem is that I need to always display 7 bars on the screen width while maintaining horizontal padding. I'm not sure how to calculate that.

The second problem is detecting when, after a swipe, the new bar is taller than the previous ones, and then triggering an action. I don't know how to do this either.

Do I need to use Layout() and Measurables for this?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set item width with

```
val padding = 12.dp
val itemCount = 7
val screenWidthDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val itemWidth = (screenWidthDp - (itemCount + 1) * padding.value) / itemCount
```

or you can wrap LazyRow with `BoxWithConstraints` and get maxWidh param instead of `LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp` and apply same way.

To get tallest item you need to provide more info about how ChartBar is constructed. If they are items with varying height you can do it as below.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ChartTest() {

    val charts = remember {
        List(50) {
            Random.nextInt(40, 500)
        }
    }

    val padding = 12.dp
    val itemCount = 7
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)

    scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo

    var tallestItem by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    var currentMaxHeight by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(tallestItem) {
        if (tallestItem > currentMaxHeight) {
            currentMaxHeight = tallestItem
            Toast.makeText(context, "Tallest item $tallestItem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    val screenWidthDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
    val itemWidth = (screenWidthDp - (itemCount + 1) * padding.value) / itemCount
    LazyRow(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = padding),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
            .onPlaced {
                val newHeight = it.size.height
                if (newHeight > tallestItem) {
                    tallestItem = newHeight
                }

                if (currentMaxHeight == 0) {
                    currentMaxHeight = newHeight
                }
            },
        reverseLayout = true,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(padding),
        state = scrollState
    ) {

        itemsIndexed(charts) { index, data ->
            ChartBar(
                modifier = Modifier.width(itemWidth.dp).height(charts[index].dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ChartBar(
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Box(modifier.background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)))
}
```

If they contain data how tall they are you can use
`scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo`

And this can be done as

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ChartTest2() {

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier.height(400.dp)
    ) {

        val context = LocalContext.current
        val density = LocalDensity.current

        val charts = remember {
            List(50) {
                Random.nextInt(40, 400)
            }
        }

        val padding = 24.dp
        val itemCount = 7
        val itemWidth = (maxWidth.value - (itemCount + 1) * padding.value) / itemCount

        val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)

        var currentMaxHeight by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0)
        }

        val tallestItem by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                val visibleItemsInfo = scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                var maxHeight = 0
                if (visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty()) {
                    visibleItemsInfo.forEach {
                        val index = it.index
                        maxHeight = charts[index].coerceAtLeast(maxHeight)
                    }
                }

                if (currentMaxHeight == 0) {
                    currentMaxHeight = (maxHeight * density.density).toInt()
                }
                (maxHeight * density.density).toInt()
            }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(tallestItem) {
            if (tallestItem > currentMaxHeight) {
                currentMaxHeight = tallestItem
                Toast.makeText(context, "Tallest item $tallestItem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        LazyRow(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = padding),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red),
            reverseLayout = true,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(padding),
            state = scrollState
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(charts) { index, data ->
                ChartBar(
                    modifier = Modifier.width(itemWidth.dp).fillMaxHeight(),
                    barHeight = charts[index].dp
                )
            }
        }

    }

}

@Composable
private fun ChartBar(
    modifier: Modifier,
    barHeight: Dp
) {
    Column(modifier) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Box(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(barHeight)
                .background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can ask it as a separate question if you wish. But what you do is you get `scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` which shows items on screen. But it's initially empty because of that you don't get any items and need to check before doing any operations. Instead of height you can pass the index of tallest item.  `currentMaxHeight ` is there to not trigger event without scroll because there can be several times items can be bigger than each other

Comment: And inside launchedEffect i trigger one time action. You can easily change this to index instead of tallestItemHeight but you can ask this as a question with more information if you prefere

Comment: And inside LaunchedEffect after action is triggered i set currentMaxHeight to be tallest to compare on scroll again

Comment: When I scroll I color the highest bar on red.
Everything is great but it lags a bit. Is there any way to improve performance?

Comment: derivedState is actually the performant one. That's why i used it. When you get items that change on every frame you use it.  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#use-derivedstateof